# isSame() function in moment.js or Date Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, date, momentjs

I need to validate the date from the user and check if it is in a particular format. If yes, then it will be accepted else it will not be. I am looking for sort of

```
value.match("regular expression")
```

The above works fine if, I  have to choose from few formats. So, I came across this moment.js and interested in knowing how to use isSame(). I tried implementing it but unsuccessful.  Like :

```
var x=moment("MM/DD/YYYY") ;
x.isSame("28-02-1999");  // am getting false which is right
var x=moment("28-02-1999","DD-MM-YYYY") ;
x.isSame("28-02-1999");  // am getting false which is wrong
```

So, please help in that.
Thanks

Comment: Though I have resolved my problem but still I need more information about the above function. I have solved it with reference to this question    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227862/how-to-test-a-string-is-valid-date-or-not-using-moment

Answer (score 143, accepted):

### [Docs - Is Same](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/)

> Check if a moment is the same as another moment.
>
> `moment('2010-10-20').isSame('2010-10-20'); // true`
>
> If you want to limit the granularity to a unit other than milliseconds, 
>   pass the units as the second parameter.
>
> `moment('2010-10-20').isSame('2009-12-31', 'year'); // false`
>   `moment('2010-10-20').isSame('2010-01-01', 'year'); // true`
>   `moment('2010-10-20').isSame('2010-12-31', 'year'); // true`
>   `moment('2010-10-20').isSame('2011-01-01', 'year'); // false`

Your code

```
var x=moment("28-02-1999","DD-MM-YYYY"); // working
x.isSame("28-02-1999"); // comparing x to an unrecognizable string
```

If you try `moment("28-02-1999")`, you get an invalid date. So comparing x to an invalid date string returns false.

To fix it, either use the [default date format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) (ISO 8601):

```
var x = moment("28-02-1999","DD-MM-YYYY");
x.isSame("1999-02-28"); // YYYY-MM-DD
```

Or pass `isSame` a moment object.

```
var x = moment("28-02-1999","DD-MM-YYYY");
x.isSame( moment("28-02-1999","DD-MM-YYYY") );
```

Comment: Some useful info i found on the doc. I was looking for something that matches string in the format as 'DD/MM/YYYY', so if you say the unit as 'day' it will do the work.
From Moment Doc: When including a second parameter, it will match all units equal or larger. Passing in month will check month and year. Passing in day will check day, month, and year.