# React DatePicker Bootstrap up to date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, datepicker

I searched for a good `datepicker` in `React` using `bootstrap` style. But everything I found wasn't working well or was not up to date...

I'm working with `React 15.0.2` and `Boostrap 3.3.6`

Does anyone know a good `datepicker` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [react-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/quri/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker) that works well. Yet, it requires CSS addition in case you use bootswatch theme. Besides, It can require some z-index adjustments depending on where you display it. Otherwise it works just fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I tried but I get some issues... First css seems not load, but I add a reference in my gulp.babel.js file. And  second when I click in a date inside the datepicker somes erros are shown (Uncaught TypeError: t.isSame is not a function) (Uncaught Invariant Violation: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 5, pending 4) Do you have an idea ?

Comment: [css](https://github.com/quri/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker/tree/master/css) must be included in your index.html and enclosed in a script tag

Comment: It may be an error with `moment` usages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335803/issame-function-in-moment-js-or-date-validation . Did you use `moment`?

Comment: In my project css (for componants) must not be placed in index.html but referenced in gulp.babel.js. But anyway, thanks for your reply, I'll seek by myself.

Comment: Yes, I use Moment, I'll check on that

Comment: That's was a problem with moment, thanks :) There is just css problem left and it will be fix. Thank you for help

Comment: this didn't really work out of the box for me.
using bootstrap form controls with type date and time works better IMHO.
See other replies

Answer (score 59):

If you are using react-bootstrap, you can add `type="date"` to `<Form.Control>`. More information at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date.

But you should note that `<input type="date">` is implemented differently by each browser!

```
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
    
....
    
<Form.Control type="date" />
```

Without react-bootstrap

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: well that was easy!

Comment: Why isn't this feature documented on their website? It's amazing.

Comment: This is the best solution I've found so far.

Comment: awesome. Good find.

Comment: Note that this doesn't seem to store time

Comment: Yes! Not documented but they support type="date" and type="time" and they are both AWESOME! (i wonder if this is an unreleased feature, there may be small issues with them). 
but @carkod is right, ill have to make a timezone picker myself.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `react-bootstrap` and noticed that the many npm packages are not working and/or not satisfying my design. So I wrote my own component with the only dependency on react-bootstrap/Button however you could change to regular html `<button>`.

[image: DatePicker React Bootstrap]

```
import { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

const weekDays = { nl: ['Ma', 'Di', 'Wo', 'Do', 'Vr', 'Za', 'Zo'] };

const FollowUp = ({ selectedDate, onChange }) => {
  const [showDate, setShowDate] = useState(new Date(selectedDate));

  // first day of the month, CAREFULL: object will change by for loop!
  const firstDayThisMonth = new Date(showDate.getFullYear(), showDate.getMonth(), 1);
  // getDay sunday=0 and we monday=0
  const dayOfWeek = (firstDayThisMonth.getDay() + 6) % 7;
  // first day of next month
  const firstDayNextMonth = new Date(showDate.getFullYear(), showDate.getMonth() + 1, 1);

  // loop whole month and keep in memo to save 1ms per time
  const month = useMemo(() => {
    const m = [];
    for (let d = firstDayThisMonth; d < firstDayNextMonth; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
      m.push(new Date(d));
    }
    return m;
  }, [showDate]);

  return (
    <div className="hl-followus">
      <div className="hl-month d-flex flex-wrap flex-row align-items-baseline justify-content-between px-3 pt-3 bg-primary text-light">
        {selectedDate.getFullYear()}
      </div>
      <div className="hl-month d-flex flex-wrap flex-row align-items-baseline justify-content-between px-3 pb-3 bg-primary text-white h2">
        {selectedDate.toLocaleString('nl-nl', {
          weekday: 'short',
          day: 'numeric',
          month: 'long',
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="hl-month d-flex flex-wrap flex-row align-items-baseline justify-content-between px-2 py-2">
        <Button
          onClick={() => setShowDate(new Date(showDate.setMonth(showDate.getMonth() - 1)))}
          className={`hl-day-button rounded-circle p-0 hl-bc1 border-white'}`}
          variant="light"
        >
          <i className="fas fa-chevron-left" />
        </Button>
        <div className="h5">
          {showDate.toLocaleString('nl-nl', { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' })}
        </div>
        <Button
          onClick={() => setShowDate(new Date(showDate.setMonth(showDate.getMonth() + 1)))}
          className="hl-day-button rounded-circle p-0 hl-bc0 border-0"
          variant="light"
        >
          <i className="fas fa-chevron-right" />
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div className="hl-month d-flex flex-wrap flex-row">
        {weekDays.nl.map((weekDay) => (
          <div key={weekDay} className="hl-day  d-flex justify-content-center">
            <small>{weekDay}</small>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="hl-month d-flex flex-wrap flex-row  ">
        <div style={{ width: `${dayOfWeek * 14.28}%` }} />
        {month.map((day) => {
          const highlightSelectedDate =
            selectedDate &&
            selectedDate.getDate() === day.getDate() &&
            selectedDate.getMonth() === day.getMonth() &&
            selectedDate.getYear() === day.getYear();
          return (
            <div key={day} className="hl-day d-flex justify-content-center">
              <Button
                onClick={() => onChange(day)}
                className={`hl-day-button rounded-circle p-0 ${!highlightSelectedDate &&
                  'hl-bc0 border-0'}`}
                variant={highlightSelectedDate ? 'primary' : 'light'}
              >
                {day.getDate()}
              </Button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <style jsx>
        {`
          .hl-month {
            width: 350px;
          }
          .hl-day {
            flex: 0 0 14.28%;
          }
          .hl-followus :global(.hl-day-button) {
            width: 36px;
            height: 36px;
          }
        `}
      </style>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FollowUp;
```

Answer (score 3):

React bootstrap using type as date:

import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import { useState } from "react";

```
export default function App() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <div className="App">
     
              <Form.Control
                type="date"
                name="datepic"
                placeholder="DateRange"
                value={date}
                onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}
              />
          
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like ravthiru said react-bootstrap [form controls](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/forms/form-control/) with type *"data"* and *"time"* will be the easiest one to go for and wont require any additional packages.

I personally like [react-date-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-range) which is quite customizable.

A heavier, complete, customizable alternative is to use [material-ui pickers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/pickers)

You can try them [here](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datetime-picker)