# Check if date is a valid one

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

Following is the scenario:

I have a `String` date and a date format which is different. Ex.:
date: 2016-10-19
dateFormat: "DD-MM-YYYY".

I need to check if this date is a valid date.

I have tried following things

```
var d = moment("2016-10-19",dateFormat);
```

`d.isValid()` is returning `false` every time. Does not Moment.js parse the date in the given format?

Then I tried to format the date in `DD-MM-YYYY` first and then pass it to Moment.js:

```
var d = moment("2016-10-19").format(dateFormat);
var date = moment(d, dateFormat);
```

Now `date.isValid()` is giving me the desired result, but here the Moment.js date object is created twice. How can I avoid this? Is there a better solution?

FYI I am not allowed to change the `dateFormat`.

Comment: Are you not allowed to change the value of dateFormat? In that case, you will have to change the format of the input, since 2016-10-19 is YYYY-MM-DD, not DD-MM-YYYY. What are you allowed to change?

Comment: The input is coming from date picker. Can't change that too :(

Comment: May I ask why you are not allowed to change the dateFormat variable?
var d = moment("19-10-2016", "DD-MM-YYYY"); would solve your problems as far as I'm concerned

Comment: really can't say. But that is not in my control to change that value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test a string is valid date or not using moment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227862/how-to-test-a-string-is-valid-date-or-not-using-moment)

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Was able to find the solution. 
Since the date I am getting is in ISO format, only providing date to moment will validate it, no need to pass the dateFormat.

```
var date = moment("2016-10-19");
```

And then `date.isValid()` gives desired result.

Comment: Does anyone know what the current preferred method is now? This method now throws the following "Deprecation Warning": moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.

Comment: @Andrew Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263380/deprecation-warning-moment-construction-falls-back-to-js-date, https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2535

Comment: Just a heads up that this doesn't always work: `var a = moment('12345'); a.isValid() // is true` This fails because moment will fall back to the default date object if it can't parse the date. And the default date object will always return a date (just not the one you want.)

Comment: That Github thread, the first comments outlines why it's deprecated but doesn't provide an alternative for checking invalid dates. When using `moment('1234').isValid()` as documented it still throws a deprecation notice.

Comment: need to add that `moment('02').isValid() === true`, so you might want to be careful with that

Comment: Also `moment('abcde 1').isValid() === true`

Comment: Warning: isValid() is not in any way reliable without a format. Do not be burnt

Comment: This is a wrong answer because I always get true whatever string I pass in

Comment: var date = moment("2016-10-32")
this is not valid date but it is returning date is valid

Comment: Also `moment(undefined).isValid() === true` (?)

Answer (score 168):

`var date = moment('2016-10-19', 'DD-MM-YYYY', true);`

You should add a third argument when invoking `moment` that enforces strict parsing.  Here is the relevant portion of the moment documentation http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ It is near the end of the section.

Comment: This has no effect.

Comment: this answer should be the correct answer........@Begueradj this has effect, try using different values, sometimes correct and sometimes wrong

Comment: And you can read about strict parsing [here](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/)

Comment: This will let you enter 0000 as a year

Answer (score 50):

I just found a really messed up case.

```
moment('Decimal128', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid() // true
```

Comment: `moment('Decimal128', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid() // false`.   Use strict mode :)   https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/

Comment: Strict mode works. Weird that this has to be strict though.

Answer (score 24):

#### How to check if a string is a valid date using Moment, when the date and date format are different

Sorry, but did any of the given solutions on this thread actually answer the question that was asked?

> I have a String date and a date format which is different. Ex.:
> date: 2016-10-19
> dateFormat: "DD-MM-YYYY".
> I need to check if this date is a valid date.

The following works for me...

```
const date = '2016-10-19';
const dateFormat = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
const toDateFormat = moment(new Date(date)).format(dateFormat);
moment(toDateFormat, dateFormat, true).isValid();

// Note I: `new Date()` circumvents the warning that
//   Moment throws (https://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/),
//   but may not be optimal.

// Note II: passing `true` as third argument to `moment()` enables strict-mode
//   https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/
```

But honestly, don't understand why `moment.isDate()`([as documented](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-a-date/)) only accepts an object. Should also support a string in my opinion.

Comment: if we pass true as 3rd argument for moment, it check's for exact date format.

Answer (score 22):

Here you go: [Working Fidddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/9j4n8vy9/23/)

```
$(function(){
  var dateFormat = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
  alert(moment(moment("2012-10-19").format(dateFormat),dateFormat,true).isValid());
});
```

Comment: Like I said the dateFormat is 'DD-MM-YYYY' and I am not allowed to change it.

Comment: Oh i see. Let me see on that.

Comment: Is it allowed to change the date string here `2016-10-19`?

Comment: Nope. That is coming from date picker

Comment: Can't you modify it after it comes from datepicker and before you input it to `var d = moment("2016-10-19",dateFormat);`?

Comment: That is what I did in the second solution that I mentioned in description but that results in creating two moment objects which I want to avoid.

Comment: @Ganesh You don't have to modify `dateFormat` or `dateString`.

Comment: It outputs true but it should output false. Plus whatever I write, it gives random results

Comment: If I change the date to 25/25/2020 your solution returns true.

Comment: check with "2012-10-32" it will show date is valid but it is not a valid date.

Comment: @Glyn after changing date, did you click `Run` button on Upper Left corner of the fiddle to reload the changes?

Comment: @devverma Pl. check my comment above

Comment: @BillalBegueradj Pl. check my comment

Answer (score 19):

I use moment along with new Date to handle cases of `undefined` data values:

`const date = moment(new Date("2016-10-19"));`

because of: `moment(undefined).isValid() == true`

where as the better way: `moment(new Date(undefined)).isValid() == false`

Comment: moment(new Date('Decimal128')).isValid() // true

Answer (score 8):

```
console.log(` moment('2019-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid()?  ` +moment('2019-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid())
console.log(` moment('2019-22-01', 'YYYY-DD-MM').isValid()?  ` +moment('2019-22-01', 'YYYY-DD-MM').isValid())
console.log(` moment('2019-22-22', 'YYYY-DD-MM').isValid()?  ` +moment('2019-22-22', 'YYYY-DD-MM').isValid())
console.log(` moment('undefined', 'YYYY-DD-MM').isValid()?  ` +moment('undefined', 'YYYY-DD-MM').isValid())

 moment('2019-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid()?  true
 moment('2019-22-01', 'YYYY-DD-MM').isValid()?  true
 moment('2019-22-22', 'YYYY-DD-MM').isValid()?  false
 moment('undefined', 'YYYY-DD-MM').isValid()?  false
```

Comment: could you please add some explanation to your answer? What additional value does this add to the already existing and accepted answer?

Answer (score 7):

What I have used is moment.js

```
let value = '19-05-1994';
let check = moment(value,'DD-MM-YYYY', true).isValid();
        console.log(check) //returns true
        return check
```

Answer (score 4):

If the date is valid then the `getTime()` will always be equal to itself.

```js
var date = new Date('2019-12-12');
if(date.getTime() - date.getTime() === 0) {
    console.log('Date is valid');
} else {
    console.log('Date is invalid');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
var d = moment("2016-10-19",dateFormat);
if(!isNaN(d)) {
  // d is a valid date.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
moment("2022-10-18 04:00 AM", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm AM", true).isValid()
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this one. It is not nice but it will work as long as the input is constant format from your date picker.

It is badDate coming from your picker in this example

https://jsfiddle.net/xs8tvox9/

```
var dateFormat = 'DD-MM-YYYY'
var badDate = "2016-10-19";

var splittedDate = badDate.split('-');

if (splittedDate.length == 3) {
  var d = moment(splittedDate[2]+"-"+splittedDate[1]+"-"+splittedDate[0], dateFormat);
  alert(d.isValid())
} else {
  //incorrectFormat
}
```

Comment: Please, don't do this.