# validate date with Moment in React

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

is there a way to display a default message when the date passed to Moment is invalid?

```
<Moment fromNow>not-a-date</Moment>
```

I´m getting **Invalid Date**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
getDate() {
    if (!this.props.date || check for invalid date) {
        return "Alternative Message on Invalid date"
    }

    return  <Moment fromNow>{this.props.date}</Moment>
}

render() {
    return this.getDate()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tage a look
[Check if date is a valid one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40123747/check-if-date-is-a-valid-one)

you should not use moment as jsx element, it is an normal class.

Comment: well I´m using react moment (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment)

Answer (score 0):

```
getDate() {
    if (!this.props.date || this.props.date===" " || check for invalid date criteria) 
{
        return "Alternative Message on Invalid date"
    }

    return  <Moment fromNow>{this.props.date}</Moment>
}

render() {
    return this.getDate()
}
```