# Validate text like 'erere 03/05/2019' as illegal Date

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate text as valid date, but i am getting wrong answers

I tried libraries like moments and date-fns , the text is free
so it can be for example : 'eer 05/03/2345', for this text js Date object creates a valid date .

code examples :

var t=moment('43/05/2020','dd/MM/yyyy');
console.log(t.isValid()) //returns true
should be false

var t=moment('03/05/2020','dd/MM/yyyy',true);
console.log(t.isValid()) //returns false should be true

//using date-fns

console.log(format(new  Date('ssds 3/3/2020'), 'dd/MM/yyyy')); //returns true should be false

Comment: Can you take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40124090/479251 ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format. The format tokens are case sensitive.

```js
let t = moment('43/05/2020','DD/MM/YYYY'); 
console.log(t.isValid());

t = moment('03/05/2020','DD/MM/YYYY',true); 
console.log(t.isValid());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You can get more details over here: [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: Your answer is correct but leaving in the comments makes it confusing as they are incorrect.

Comment: The correct format solved the problem for illegal dates like : moment('43/05/2020','DD/MM/YYYY'); but for this case date is valid  moment('hghg 3/05/2020','DD/MM/YYYY');

Answer (score 0):

There are some post validating dates, if you are using moment take a look at this.

```
var dateEntered = $('#txtEnteredDate').val();

if (!moment(dateEntered,'MM-DD-YYYY').isValid()) {
  console.log('Invalid Date');
} else {
  console.log('Valid Date');
}
```

the code above was taken from this url: [Managing Dates and Times Using Moment.js](https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-dates-times-using-moment-js/)

you can also take a look to this url: [Javascript - Regex to validate date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388001/javascript-regex-to-validate-date-format)

Comment: For this case : moment('hghg 3/05/2020','DD/MM/YYYY')  date is valid==true ;